# How to store SparkR Dataframe in cassandra?

Tags: r, apache-spark, cassandra, sparkr

```
head(users) 
1 jay  chennai
2 kumar bangalore
3 vinoth Trichy
4 saswath perambalur
```

I want to store this output to cassandra table . I tried the below lines to store

```
users.write
     .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
     .options(Map( "table" -> "sparkusers", "keyspace" -> "bigdata"))
     .save()
```

throws error

> unexpected symbol in test.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options" please help me on this?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong syntax for R (That is the python/scala syntax)

```
read.df(sqlContext, source = "org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra", keyspace = "ks", table = "table")
```

See [Spark R Dataframe Documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/read.df.html)